# Any way to allow nans in python sklearn K nearest neighbors?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I'm using pythons sklenar KNeighborsRegressors and getting an error about missing data ("Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype"). In the case of my dataset, missing data actually means something very significant, so I can't replace the nans by forward-filling or using the mean or anything like that. So I have to keep the blank data somehow. Is there any way to make sklearn's K neighbors allow that blank data?

Obviously, it's not clear what being "near" nan means, but I'd like to define that as infinite distance, so that values only match that neighbor if they are also nan. 
  Is there any way to make sklearn do that? I thought about maybe replacing the nans with some gigantic value (like 9999999999999999999999) that's so far away from every value that it looks infinite, but maybe there's a better way?

Comment: You can try using numpy's inbuilt [`np.nan_to_num()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html).

Comment: But that's just replacing the Nans with 0, right? Then i'd lose something important (for my dataset "blank" means something very specific and important, but 0 is just like any other number)

Comment: Plain `NaN`s yes, but its replacing +/- `inf` with very large pos/neg numbers.    Otherwise its very difficult to tell what the number represented by a `NaN` was meant to be (hence its interpreted as `NaN` instead of `inf` for example).